# Wordpress multisite count posts in category

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, multisite

I'm running a multisite with a main site and 3sub sites (the number of subsites will be over 200 at the end). Now on every site I have a category called A, Category called B, and Category called C. On my main site I want to publish a count of all posts made on all subsites, all posts made on all subsites in category A, all posts made on all subsites in category B, all posts made on all subsites in category C. So I get the output like this:

All posts: 100

Posts in category A: 20

Posts in category B: 30

Posts in category C: 50

Of course a post can be in categories A, B at the same time and can only be counted one time.

I found the way to count all posts.

```
<?php

global $wpdb;
$post_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_2_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post'  "  );
$post_count1 = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_3_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post'  "  );
$post_count2 = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_4_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post'  "  );

$sum = $post_count + $post_count1 + $post_count2;

echo "<p>All posts {$sum}</p>";

?>
```

I'm having trubles with the Posts in certain categories. Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php

global $wpdb;
$wp_count_terms = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_2_term_taxonomy WHERE term_taxonomy_id = '22'   "  );
$wp_count_terms1 = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_3_term_taxonomy WHERE term_taxonomy_id = '16'   "  );
$wp_count_terms2 = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_4_term_taxonomy WHERE term_taxonomy_id = '13'   "  );

$sum = $wp_count_terms + $wp_count_terms1 + $$wp_count_terms2;

echo "<p>Posts in category A: {$sum}</p>";

?>
```

But it's not working correctly. Am I on the right track at all?

Comment: You could try SQL COUNT -function to count all the post rows from database. 
Instructions for SQL COUNT can be found here: 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp

Comment: thanks for the tip, see edit

Comment: Found an answer you can find it on the [link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/212321/multisite-posts-in-categories-on-network/212330#212330).